# how to use java function with frida?

Tags: reverse-engineering, frida

I need to use java function with my own arguments inside an Android app, the function is as follows:

```
private String targetFunc(int a1,int a2,int a3) {
        -----(some math things)
        return result;
    }
```

I need to be able to use this function with my own arguments, I can parse arguments of this function when it called etc,but I don`t know how to use/invoke it.

Comment: Just like in Java, you need an instance of a class and then you can call the desired method on it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are referring to function hooking using frida. Use the following steps:

1. Find the intended class.

```
    var c = Java.use('<your_class_name>')
```

2. If the method is a static method, go to step 3. Otherwise, create an instance of the specific class.

```
    var c_ins = c.$new()
```

3. Hook the method.

```
    c.method_name.implementation = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        // do your stuff with arg1, arg2, arg3
        // return if necessary.
```

For details, look into this [link](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/mobile-apps-pentesting/android-app-pentesting/frida-tutorial/frida-tutorial-2).